# Implement of database in MongoDB by linking many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have employee model where i have many controller 
like

```
jobs_controller.rb
contacts_controller.rb
personals_controller.rb
dependets_controller.rb
```

They are all related to Employee controller.
I am using MongoDb as I have different controller i have different model too. 
In my dashboard i have to show related employee details. where one field is from contacts controller,another from dependents_controller,another from personal controller.
Here i have to call all Models and fetch one field from each Model. 
Can i customize this code by showing each field from one related Model.
I am using devise. cant i store id of each user related data and call throug user model?
I am messed up.. If yes then how?
In my employee controller

```
def index
    @employees = Employee.all
    Employee.includes(:dependants).each do |dependant|
     p dependant.firstname #example of pulling data for that related entity
     end


  end
```

Also How can i locate to the related person data??

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this section of the mongoid docs : http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html
It should give you a good indication of how you can implement relational logic within your models.

However, I'd highly recommend you read this first:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling

in particular the referencing and atomicity sections.

I was caught out in the past not fully grasping the differences between mongo and transactional DB engines (like innodb) which caused me to redesign my models mid way through a project.

Clarification upon request

You could set your models up like this as described by my first link:

```
class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :address, type: String
  field :work, type: String
  has_many :dependants
end

class Dependant
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :firstname, type: String
  field :lastname, type: String
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

In your controller you can then access the dependants data through the employee:

```
#this example loops through every employee in the collection
Employee.includes(:dependants).each do |employee|
  employee.dependants.each do |dependant|
   p dependant.firstname #example of pulling data for that related entity
  end
end
```

Comment: can u give me some coding example related to my controller? If so then it will male me to catch my answer fast

Comment: i tried it .. but i didnot get it. Suppose I have 2 field for employee  field :address, type: String
 field :work, type: String     and two field for dependant field :firstname, type: String
  field :lastname, type: String    Then how can i implement that in Model and also in employee controller . Can u edit the code. Thanks

Comment: my index controller of employee is like this  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
    Employee.includes(:dependants).each do |dependant|
  p dependant.firstname #example of pulling data for that related entity
end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @employees }
    end
  end It gives error undefined method `firstname' for #<Employee:0x0000000201a2f0>

Comment: @regmiprem, see my last edit, this code looks like the previous version

Comment: I did as i edit my question but i get error undefined method `firstname' for #<Employee:0x00000001eff6e0>For a related employee of name prem , How can i fetch his dependant value. As i have two controller how can i relate them as same person value in my employee controller.